# Euler’s theorem: any sequence of rotations = one rotation about some axis

Tags: computer-science

While learning about transformations in Computer Graphics,I couldn't get why any sequence of rotations is actually equal to one rotation about some axis by Euler's theorem as stated in [Computer Graphics](http://1drv.ms/1xiRdKS).

Comment: Did you read this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh:I couldn't get what they meant in wikipedia.